# Create IEnumerable DropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

How can I create an `IEnumerable` dropdown list in ASP MVC 5 ?

I'm using this but it shows me error :

```
  public ActionResult EditStudent()
    {
        ViewBag.Reshte = new SelectList(_db.Tbl_Reshte, "ReshteID", "ReshteName");
        ViewBag.Paye = new SelectList(_db.Tbl_Paye, "PayeID", "PayeName");
        return View();
    }
```

View

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Reshte)
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Reshte, (SelectList) ViewBag.Reshte, "-- رشته دانش آموز ---", htmlAttributes: new {@class = "form-control"})
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Paye)
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Paye, (SelectList) ViewBag.Paye, "-- پایه تحصیلی دانش آموز --", htmlAttributes: new {@class = "form-control"})
</div>
```

> The ViewData item that has the key 'Reshte' is of type 'System.Int32' but must be of type 'IEnumerable'.

```
 public partial class Tbl_Reshte
{
    public Tbl_Reshte()
    {
        Tbl_Pye_Reshte = new HashSet<Tbl_Pye_Reshte>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int ReshteID { get; set; }

    [StringLength(100)]
    public string ReshteName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Tbl_Pye_Reshte> Tbl_Pye_Reshte { get; set; }
}
```

.

```
 public partial class Tbl_Paye
{
    public Tbl_Paye()
    {
        Tbl_Pye_Reshte = new HashSet<Tbl_Pye_Reshte>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int PayeID { get; set; }

    [StringLength(100)]
    public string PayeName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Tbl_Pye_Reshte> Tbl_Pye_Reshte { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Correct title and first sentence: IEnumerable, not IEnumerabel

Comment: ok . thanks . do you have guide for me ?

Comment: Can you add the model class you're using?

Comment: i Add  . . . . . .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to define new viewModel like below

```
 public class SampleViewModel
 {
    [Display(Name = "رشته")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "لطفا یکی از رشته ها را انتخاب نمایید")]
    public int ReshteId { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> ReshteSelectListItems { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "پایه تحصیلی")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "لطفا یکی از پایه ها را انتخاب نمایید")]
    public int PayeId { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> PayeSelectListItems { get; set; }

    //other field....
 }
```

and your **controller**

```
public ActionResult Add()
    {
        var model = new SampleViewModel
        {
            PayeSelectListItems = _db.paye.Select(p=>new SelectListItem {Text =p.PayeName ,Value = PayeID.tostring() }).toList(),
            //ReshteSelectListItems = ...

        };
        return View(model);
    }
```

finally your **View**

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(p => p.ReshteId, Model.ReshteSelectListItems , new { @class = "form-control" })
```